# SP - C# Delete Item - Error message: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: list, splistitem, delete, runwithelevatedprivileges, error-handling

When i trying to delete listItem from list and anonymous access in site perm(*for Fund3*)  is **disabled** my code throw exception. Where anonymous access is enable everything is OKAY-> items are deleted.....

**Exception:**

> Error message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(Unauthoriz
>   edAccessException ex)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl
>   , Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBase
>   TypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags
>   , Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTr Error stackTrace:    at Microso
>   ft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl, String b
>   strListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress
>   , Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.DeleteCore(DeleteOp deleteOp)
>      at **Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Delete()**
>      at ClearLibsInFund.Program.b__0()

**My code:**

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
 {
     try
     {
         using (var oSite = new SPSite(args[0])) //argument for Console application
         {
             using (var oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
             {
                 oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                         var list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);

                         var queryItems = new SPQuery();
                         queryItems.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'></View>";

                         var items = list.GetItems(queryItems);

                        //Option 1
                         for (int i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                         {
                             items[i].Recycle();
                         }

                         //Option 2
                         //foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
                         //{
                         //    SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listitem.ID);
                         //    itemToDelete.Recycle();
                         //}

                         //Option 3
                         //while (items.Count > 0)
                         //{
                         //    items[0].Recycle();
                         //}

                        oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                 }

             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message + " Error stackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
     }
 });
```

Where is the problem, because i run code with **RunWithElevatedPrivileges** and which option to delete must use(best practice)...

Comment: Are you running your console app as an Administrator (Right click --> "Run as administrator")?

Comment: Option n.1 is ok, but it's better if you get item count firstrly (better for performance): 
var itemCount = items.Count;
for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: yes i running cmd as an Administrator... and pass url as argument... When i use cmd with another site where anonymous access is disable... is all OKay... I dont know the reason..

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why it doesn't work in case Anonymous is disabled... But in all cases, can you try without `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` and rather with `SPUserToken.SystemAccount`, and use

```
try
{
   using (var oSite = new SPSite("http://dd-spdev1:23840/EN/HR/DKC/Fund3/", SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
   {
      using (var oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
      {
         oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         var list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
         . . .
```

Also: why do you have a hard-coded URL `http://dd-spdev1:23840/EN/HR/DKC/Fund3`? Does it mean you're not targetting the current SPWeb your Web part (or user control) is running in? That could also be a problem...

And about the ways to delete items in a loop, I personally like the option #1.

**EDIT**
OK, you said in a comment a console app it is.
That's a completely different story. Regarding security and access control, a console app has nothing to do with a Web context:

1. Connections to DB will be made with under the identity of the user who launches the app (usually the user who logged on the server... ho yes, a console app making use of the server-side API must be used on the SharePoint server, not remotely)
2. --> No need for privileges elevation. Its completely useless since there's no context to go back under.
3. --> The user who runs the app must have a read-write access to the SQL content DB!
4. I *think* `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is not needed in a console app context.
5. The user must also have permissions at the SharePoint.
6. See some other inputs I wrote in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204088/site-collection-administrator-rights-or-full-control-on-web-application-user-pol/204095#204095), that may also apply here.

Comment: URL is hardcoded for the exam, URL is args[0], because VS project is C# console application

Comment: see my updated code

Comment: Ho, concole app is anoher story...